# Is it possible to emplace an instance inside std::optional w/o checking/destructing the previous one?

Tags: c++, option-type, c++17, emplace

Let's say we have a variable

```
std::optional<T> x;
```

of type `std::optional<T>` for some type `T`.
If I want to call a constructor of `T` inside `x` and initialize it, I can call the member function `std::optional::emplace`. As I know, this member function checks if the instance already exists (that is, `bool(x)` evaluates to `true`), and if that's the case, it first destroys the previously constructed instance and then re-initialize it using the constructor and arguments provided.

I'm wondering if it is possible to do only initialization w/o this checking and destruction. When dealing with `std::optional`, it seems quite common to first check if the instance exists and then do some separate works depending on the result. Therefore, it seems reasonable to argue that quite often when we need to emplace an instance inside `std::optional`, we already know that it does not contain any initialized instance. Hence, it seems reasonable to provide an "unsafe-version" of `std::optional::emplace` that does not check and destroy the previous instance, but `std::optional` does not have such a member function. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Perhaps, if there are some guarantees about memory layout for `std::optional` (which I guess not), then I can call placement `new` operator directly...

Comment: I would hope a decent optimizing compiler would be able to remove these useless checks. Did you check if this check is still in after optimizing?

Comment: @JVApen Seems often it indeed does, but not always, especially when construction is done inside another function (which the compiler failed to inline).

Comment: Have you already tried adding assertions on it being empty?

Comment: @JVApen Of course. It seems `std::optional::emplace` itself seems often isn't inlined, resulting useless double check.

Comment: How about the "in place" constructor `constexpr explicit optional( std::in_place_t, Args&&... args )` ?

Comment: BTW, I doubt that the check is the bottleneck of the application.

Comment: @Jarod42 You mean, use placement `new` for the `std::optional` instance directly to call the constructor you mentioned, right? Sounds good! And for the other comment: well, of course not a bottleneck, but it's annoying, isn't it?

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to optimize your program. If that's the case, I highly recommend using a profile to measure the execution time before attempting to change your code. You may find that the bottlenecks are in unexpected places.

Comment: @JunekeyJeon: "*but it's annoying, isn't it?*" How? It doesn't affect the way your code looks or how you would have to write it. It isn't visible at the cite of the call in any way. The only possible effect it could have is performance.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible. And no, calling placement `new` directly onto the memory wouldn't help either since you'd also have to set the flag in the `optional` indicating that the `optional` is engaged - and you can't do that externally.

> Therefore, it seems reasonable to argue that quite often when we need to emplace an instance inside `std::optional`, we already know that it does not contain any initialized instance

That's not a strong argument. `emplace()` is simply a potential optimization on top of `operator=`, there's no implicit hint in the use of such a function about the current state of the `optional`.

Also, if your code is structured like:

```
if (!o) {
    // stuff
    o.emplace(some, args, here);
}
```

You can rest assured that your compiler will see the duplicate branch between the `explicit operator bool()` check and the internal `emplace()` check and collapse them together, so there will not be an extra branch.

Comment: By "guarantees about memory layout" I meant to include the guarantee on the position of the flag variable. And I see no reason not to provide a "hinted" version of `emplace` together with the normal one. A name such as `unsafe_emplace` may well prevent programmers from overusing it, I think. And I looked at the assembly generated and there were double check because the compiler failed to inline `std::optional::emplace` in spite of the maximum optimization flag.